# What are the correct ImageMagick parameters to create an image with these properties?

Tags: imagemagick

An **external program** is converting an image so that the properties change from those on the **left** to those on the **right**.
[image]

I am trying to replicate these **exact** same changes with **Imagemagick**.

When I apply **strip/cmyk**, I get the number of colors and disk size correct:

```
convert CMYK_jpg.jpg -strip -colorspace CMYK CMYK_jpg_stripped_cmyk.jpg
```

[image]

But when I try to then change the resolution to **300x300** as well like this:

```
convert CMYK_jpg.jpg -strip -colorspace CMYK -resample 300x300 CMYK_jpg_stripped_cmyk.jpg
```

then it changes the **DPI correctly**, but all the **other values** are incorrect:

[image]

**What are the correct ImageMagick parameters to generate an image with all the desired properties?**

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the parameter `-density 300` 
so the full command would be:

```
convert CMYK_jpg.jpg -density 300 -strip -colorspace CMYK CMYK_jpg_stripped_cmyk.jpg
```